# How to import a file from another folder in a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

My project structure looks like this

```
pythonProject
|
|-__init__.py
|
|- a 
|  |- file_a.py 
|  |-__init__.py
|
|- b 
   |- file_b.py 
   |-__init__.py
```

I've also attached the image of my project's structure below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7UcD.png)

My `file_a.py` looks like:

```
class class_a:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def show(self):
        print('class A')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

My `file_b.py` looks like:

```
from pythonProject.a.file_a import class_a

class class_b:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def show(self):
        a = class_a()
        a.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = class_b()
```

But I keep getting an error  `No module named 'pythonProject'`. All the folders do have `__init__.py` file.  What am I doing wrong?

On the terminal, I run the command `python b/file_b.py` from inside the pythonProject.

Also, I would not like to add project path using sys library.

Thanks.

Things I've tried.

1. I added all the `__init__.py` file in all the folders. But all of them are empty. Should they have any specific references?
2. I tried the import line to `..a.file_a import class_a`. Then I get the error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`
3. I tried the import line to `a.file_a import class_a` but then the error is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time). While this question isn't directly about relative imports, it seems that your design is suffering from the same issues with the relationship between packages and directories and the differences between modules and scripts that are addressed in that question.

Comment: In order for Python to be able to import the package `pythonProject`, the directory _containing_ that directory needs to be on the Python path. This is usually done either by installing your project as a distribution package or by ensuring that the directory containing `pythonProject` is on your Python path.

Comment: Also, as described in the dupe, using `python ./dir/file.py` runs that file as a top-level script that _is not part of a package_. You want to run a module inside of a package, so you should use `python -m pythonProject.subpkg.module`.

Comment: @Brian I think the linked question has the answer to my question. I still have to go through the complete comment. But essentially these is a mismatch between a module and how I'm running it as a script. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem appears to be with your `if __name__ == "main"` condition in files `a.py` and `b.py`. Instead of `"main",` the correct string is `"__main__"` (double underscores on each side)

Change the condition in both files to `if __name__ == "__main__":` and try running file `b.py` again. This should resolve the error

> No module named 'pythonProject'.

In terms of imports, you can import class a from file `a.py` using the absolute import syntax in file `b.py`

`from pythonProject.a.file_a import class_a`

As long as you run file `b.py` from within the `pythonProject` directory, this should work.

Comment: that doesn't resolve the problem. My understanding is also that it should work but it gives me the same error: `from pythonProject.a.file_a import class_a` followed by 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythonProject'`

Comment: _"As long as you run file `b.py` from within the `pythonProject` directory, this should work."_ Shouldn't that be from the directory _containing_ `pythonProject`? If their CWD is `pythonProject`, then `pythonProject` won't be discoverable on the Python path. Instead, `a` and `b` will be discovered as top-level packages. In any case, they likely want to invoke `file_b.py` as a module (`python -m pythonProject.b.file_b`) instead of as a top-level script